# How can I build on top of an XCArchive file?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcarchive

I have a client which is delivering me an XCArchive file to be used as the base layer of a project. I am to extend the base classes and add customization. How can I use an XCArchive file in my project? Is there any way to convert or extract a precompiled library (.a) or attach as a framework somehow, add it as a target, ect...

Not sure where to begin on this one.

Comment: Need more information. Is this .xcarchive an archive of a framework? What are you trying to build on top of it? Are you trying to use the framework in another project? Are you trying to add code to the framework?

Answer (score 2):

Ask for the whole project. Not just the archive file.

The archive does not contain app's source code